# Disable daylight saving time in Debian Linux

Tags: linux, time, timezone

I do not want my system to use daylight saving time.

```
root@ali-debserver:~# cat /etc/timezone
Asia/Tehran

root@ali-debserver:~# cat /etc/default/rcS
#
# /etc/default/rcS
#
# Default settings for the scripts in /etc/rcS.d/
#
# For information about these variables see the rcS(5) manual page.
#
# This file belongs to the "initscripts" package.

# delete files in /tmp during boot older than x days.
# '0' means always, -1 or 'infinite' disables the feature
#TMPTIME=0

# spawn sulogin during boot, continue normal boot if not used in 30 seconds
#SULOGIN=no

# do not allow users to log in until the boot has completed
#DELAYLOGIN=no

# be more verbose during the boot process
#VERBOSE=no

# automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot
#FSCKFIX=no
```

I could not solve this problem permanently with `ntp` or `tzdate`. How do I disable daylight saving time?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what are daylights saving ?

Comment: @Kiwy Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: @jofel thank you ^^ I really didn't know the english term for that

Comment: Note that under Unix/Linux, daylight savings time is not so much *used*, but *displayed*. Any timestamp on files will be an absolute time, and timezone information is calculated when the directory is listed, so an individual program may or may not display DST. Changing the default is just that: the default (and, probably, what syslogd uses).

Answer (score 17):

There are DST-free timezone definitions provided which just define the GMT-offset, called `Etc/GMT±X`:

```
$ date
Mon Apr  7 11:08:56 CEST 2014
$ TZ=Etc/GMT-1 date
Mon Apr  7 10:09:16 GMT-1 2014
$
```

Just link/copy the one you need to `/etc/localtime` and you should be fine and DST-free:

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-1 /etc/localtime
```

**Edit:** For non-integer offsets you would be on your own.  You might build your own zone-file defining the offset you need:  Put the following lines into a file:

```
# Zone  NAME          GMTOFF  RULES FORMAT [UNTIL]
Zone    Tehran-nodst  3:25:44 -     LMT    1916
                      3:25:44 -     TMT    1946    # Tehran Mean Time
                      3:30    -     IRST   1977 Nov
                      4:00    -     IRST   1979
                      3:30    -     IRST
```

and run

```
$ zic -d . <filename>
```

This will produce a file called `Tehran-nodst` in the current directory, which you can copy to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia` and link/copy to `/etc/localtime` (only doing the last copy would be perfectly fine, too).

Comment: This works in general for timezone with integer offset, but as far as I have seen, there is no Etc/GMT+3:30 rule which would be needed for Asia/Tehran. (`TZ=GMT+3:30` works, but cannot be used for `/etc/localtime`).

Comment: Sorry, missed that Tehran has non-integer offset. Fixed the answer appropriately.  Now it should be _really_ exact.

Answer (score 0):

You need probably define your own Timezone without any [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) rules. Look at the source files of the [`tzdata` package](http://packages.qa.debian.org/t/tzdata.html) which contains the sources of the compiled files in /usr/share/zoneinfo/.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove /etc/localtime (or back up it  mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.back)
make a link to your timezone like below:

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran /etc/localtime
```

Comment: This probably does not work as the Asia/Tehran timezone uses DST rules.

Comment: @jofel how use DST rules?

Comment: @Charlesnakhel i tested this way before, not work.

Comment: @alireza.m do you have a chance to restart the server (# /sbin.init 6) and after the reboot sync the hw clock (# /usr/sbin/hwclock –systohc)

Comment: Timezone changes don't need reboots.  This just does not work since Asia/Tehran defines DST.